# Vim - CtrlP (or pathogen) loads only help pages?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, pathogen, ctrlp

i'm newbie on Vim and now I have problem:

I have installed **Pathogen** and **CtrlP** scripts on my vim. But CtrlP doesn't load properly any CtrlP's command or shortcut doesn't work, only help pages work.
It says that :CtrlP is not editor command and CtrlP's shortcuts doesn't make anything.

Pathogen.vim is under *~/.vim/autoload/*, and CtrlP is in *~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/*

Here's my .gvimrc:

```
" Enable pathogen
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

" Remove toolbars and scrollbars
set guioptions-=r " Scrollbars
set guioptions-=T " Toolbar
set guioptions-=m " Menubar

" Enable line numbers, curosorline and set colorscheme
set number
set cursorline
colo wombat

" Reload .gvimrc when saved it
au BufWritePost .gvimrc so %

" Ctrl-S file saving shortcut
nmap <C-S> :w<CR>
```

And here's how i installed scripts:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir -p .vim .vim/autoload .vim/bundle
$ curl -Sso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
    https://raw.github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
$ cd .vim
$ git clone https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim.git bundle/ctrlp.vim
$ gvim ~/.gvimrc
```

And then I wrote that .gvimcr file, and googled and googled, and came here to ask.

Comment: How do you call CtrlP? What works? What doesn't? Please describe every step.

Comment: How do you call CtrlP? What command do you use? Can you do `:h ctrlp<CR>`?

Comment: Yes, I can do `:h ctrlp<CR>`. But `:CtrlP` and <C-P> doesn't work.

Comment: what do "doesn't work" mean? `:CtrlP` is supposed to show you a partial list of the files under your current directory. Do `:cd ~/.vim` then `:CtrlP`. Do you get a list of files contained in `~/.vim`? Do you get a different list? Do you even get a list?

Comment: Nothing happens when I do `:CtrlP` or any command or shortcut of CtrlP script.

Comment: Do you see ctrlp in `:scriptnames`?

Comment: No, I didn't, but pathogen is in list.

Comment: Then ctrlp is badly installed. Try removing `.vim` from the `ctrlp.vim` directory.

Comment: I don't see anything named `.vim` in `ctrlp.vim` directory. I have deleted whole `.vim` directory and reinstalled ctrlp and pathogen. It doesn't help.

Comment: according to the snippet in your question, you have cloned ctrlp into a directory named `ctrlp.vim`, try removing the `.vim` from the dir's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, finally I solved it!

Move your `execute pathogen#infect()` and `filetype plugin indent on` to your `~/.vimrc`, I have no idea, but seems that it doesn't work if these lines are in `~/.gvimrc`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have taken wrong step at cloning CtrlP repo. @romainl already pointed that out but you fixes may not be correct.

Here is a revised steps

```
$ cd
$ mkdir -p .vim/autoload .vim/bundle
$ curl -Sso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
    https://raw.github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
$ cd .vim/bundle
# Different git command! Do it in root of /bundle!
$ git clone https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim.git
```

Now go to vim, run `:Help` to rebuild help files by Pathogen.

Should be okay now.

Comment: But now it doesn't load even Pathogen? But it didn't change anything in my `~/.vim`, final result is same as before.

Answer (score 0):

You probably created the wrong tree directory. Make sure the ctrlp.vim directory is inside bundle directory. The same happened to me because I did git clone of ctrlp plugin repository inside the bundle repository.